# Earliest source of 24,000?

Tags: history

There is said to be a connection between the 24k shechemites killed by shimon and Levi, the 24k who died in the plague with the midianites, and the 24k students of Rabbi Akiva.

I just noticed that the number of shechemites is not actually mentioned in the Torah. The earliest use of the 24k is thus the plague in the desert.

When was the number of shechemites first described?

When was the number of Akiva's students first described?

I am wondering whether those numbers were set to create a connection that may not have been there.

Comment: Not maybe the first, but refer to Megaleh Amukos 88

Comment: This post would be more compelling if you'd [edit] in an example of where you see (or have heard) the cited connection being drawn.

Comment: "There is a connection between the 24k shechemites killed by shimon and Levi, the 24k who died in the plague with the midianites, and the 24k students of Rabbi Akiva." what is the source for this claim? Is it your own conjecture?

Comment: The connection is based on a Kabbalistic teaching the R Akiva was a spark of Zimri who was a spark of Shimon. This has been become a popular topic recently due to Marc Gafni's book on the subject. Gafni quotes all his sources there: https://www.marcgafni.com/the-fourth-gate-reincarnations/

Comment: But where is the first attestation of the raw numbers? Is it as late as the renaissance?

Comment: @ClintEastwood regarding Akiva’s students, that’s flat out in the Gemara that it mentions 24k

Comment: Do you know whether a Tana or Amora said it? And what date that person lived?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Shechem:

I have seen the Shechem number attributed to the Ari.

Akiva's students
Yevamot 62b.